# How to open android app by clicking on a link in the email

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-manifest

i want to open my android app by clicking on a weblink, I sent this web link to my email/slack and tried to click the link but android app did not open.

I followed https://developer.android.com/training/app-links to create the link

links i tried - http://xxxxappdemo.com

```
    <!-- Activities -->
    <activity
        android:name=".splash.ui.SplashActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />

            <data android:host="xxxxappdemo.com" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Could you suggest what I might be wrong here please

thanks
R

Comment: An email app can do whatever it wants with links. That includes displaying the resulting pages in the email app. An email app that uses `ACTION_VIEW` might trigger your app link if app links are set up properly in the app (e.g., `assetlinks.json` on your server). If the app link works in a Web page viewed within Chrome, and the same app link does not work within the email message, that may be a policy decision of the email app.

Comment: I tried to open the link from chrome, by accessing this page link and clicking on the `http://xxxxappdemo.com` but that did not work. 
another questions assetlinks.json, is that in the app? i tried to have a look and did not find any reference to that

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/training/app-links and https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing for more on app links.

Comment: I noticed you've put your intent-filter under the Splash activity. Do you have a MainActivity file or is the splash activity your main?

Comment: @BRDroid did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

On [here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations) it mentions that you need a json file under the website you're using app links for. So first, it looks like you'll need to add a json file named `assetlinks.json` under the folder `well-known` (under your website).

Then, in Android Studio, go to Tools > App link assistant. Once it opens, click the "Open digital asset links file generator"

[image]

Then on the right side fill the details, and click "Generate details asset links file"

[image]

Then, copy the json it provides and paste it into your `assetlinks.json` file. Let me know if this works for you :)